# Asking Mobile number verification after creating new user using Google Directory API

Tags: gmail, google-directory-api, google-classroom

presently i am using Google classroom API to integrate in my .net web application.
To create new users i am using Google  Directory API.its working fine at the time of creation.But after creating new user when we log in to mail with new user its asking for **Verify your identity**.

In that window its asking for mobile number verification through text message or Voice call.how can i skip this verification and due to this verification i can't directly add a new course to that new user in my google classroom.so please any one help me on this...

Comment: In your admin console, under security->basic settings, if you select two-step verification, then users will be protected with both email and phone. You can check this link https://www.google.com/landing/2step/ fore reference

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 things to double-check in your Google Apps domain:

1. Ensure that **2-step verification** is disabled:

   - Admin console > Security > Basic settings > Two-step verification
2. Ensure that your **Company Profile** for your domain is "education":

   - Admin console > Company profile > Organisation type

We had a similar problem in our GAFE domain & while we had done step 1, it was step 2 that ensured that this was honoured.

Here's another Google support article on setting up 2FV that i found helpful: https://support.google.com/a/answer/175197?hl=en